# C++ How to run programs in Clion when you need to include OpenGL libraries?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, clion, glm-math

Hello I need to work with OpenGL and want to create my project in Clion. But Clion cannot compile and run my projects because of the libraries I need to include. I can create my own makefile and run the program in terminal, but I want to do it in the IDE. How can I make this happen?

Comment: Clion, so you are using cmake?

Comment: Which IDE? Which libraries?

Comment: the IDE is Clion, some libraries I include are glew, glfw, and jpeglib.
I think I need to use cmake but I don't know how to include those libraries to compilation phase

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you installed all libraries correctly using the compiler you configured in clion/cmake. Assuminf you have a fresh CMakeLists.txt like

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3.2)
 project(MyGL CPP)

 add_executable(demo-run main.cpp)
```

For linking your libraries you need two things. First tell the compiler where to find the include files and second which libraries to link. You could just hard code you local installation like

```
 target_link_libraries(demo-run path/to/glfw.lib path/to/opengl.lib path/to/jpeg.lib ...)
 target_include_directories(demo-run PRIVATE path/to/glfw/include path/to/opengl/include path/to/jpeg/include ...)
```

however this is not very portable and if you want to work with another compiler or on another machine your project file will fail. Instead you can use the package system of cmake

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)
find_package(JPEG REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package (OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package (GLM REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(demo-run ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} ${JPEG_LIBRARIES} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(demo-run PRIVATE ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR} ${JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR} ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${GLM_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

The glfw part is a bit tricky and works only on linux i guess see http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/build.html.

This code is not tested at all and you may need to specify some enviroment variables so cmake can find the packages or provide additional find scripts like https://github.com/lighttransport/nanogi/blob/master/cmake/FindGLM.cmake.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to use the CMake build tool which does the work generating Makefiles for you and is also directly supported by clion. When you open the directory containing a CMakeLists.txt (CMake Project File) with clion, it should be automatically be loaded and compiled (if not just hit build)

A very simple example CMake project would look like this

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.9)
project (OpenGl-Stuff)

include_directories(src)

add_executable(your-binary src/your-code.c src/your-code.h)
target_link_libraries(your-binary opengl) 
# target_link_libraries will search for libopengl on standard system paths, 
# maybe the library is not called libopengl, then you have to adjust the name above
```

this cmake project will generate the binary for you and link it against opengl